# Can I create a Google Analytics report for events related to high-frequency users?

Tags: google-analytics, users, analytics-events

I want to know what are the Google Analytics events related to users that are coming frequently i.e. more than 5 times to my website. 
Google Analytics tells the count of sessions related to the frequency of users (under Behavous> frequency & recency tab) but there is no way to know what are the actions done by the high-frequency users.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by creating a new segment in Google Analytics.

In the segment you go to Advanced and pick **Conditions**.

Now you create a filter. In the drop down pick "**Count of Sessions**" and then you choose **>= 5**.

This will filter out users with 5 or more sessions for the current date range you have selected.

Give the Segment a good name and save it.

Now you can apply the segment for any report you like i.e. Top Events.